# gulp 'default' task finishes without running callback

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have recently upgraded from gulp 3 to 4 - I have the upgrade guides, and modified my code to suit, but I am still getting some odd behaviour.

Here is a small reproducible case:

```
gulp.task('do-nothing', function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        done()
    }, 3 * 1000)
})

gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("do-nothing"), function (done) {
    console.log(`\n\n\nWHY AM I NOT BEING RUN`)
})
```

When `gulp` is run, the output is:

```
[14:10:57] Using gulpfile ~\Code\certsimple\gulpfile.js
[14:10:57] Starting 'default'...
[14:10:57] Starting 'do-nothing'...
[14:11:00] Finished 'do-nothing' after 3.01 s
[14:11:00] Finished 'default' after 3.02 s
```

There is no `WHY AM I NOT BEING RUN` printed to the console.

Why is this?

Comment: try adding return to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

```
gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("do-nothing"), function (done) {
```

Note that it has **three** arguments: the string task name, gulp.parallel(), and an anonymous function call.  That is gulp3 syntax.  Here is the gulp4 `task` function signature:

```
task([taskName], taskFunction)  // note only **two** arguments.
```

From [gulp 4 documentation for `task` signature](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task#signature).

That is why your `console.log` is never reached.  So you just need to put your anonymous function within the `gulp.parallel` argument to fix it.

```
gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("do-nothing", function (done) {
    console.log(`\n\n\nWHY AM I NOT BEING RUN`)
}));
```

Also since you are using `gulp.parallel` the `console.log` isn't going to wait for `do-nothing` to finish.

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('do-nothing', function (done) {
setTimeout(function () {
    done()
}, 3 * 1000)
})

gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("do-nothing", function (done) {
    console.log(`\n\n\nWHY AM I NOT BEING RUN`)
}))
```

Is this what you are looking for, the function is the third argument of gulp.task, which to me will not work. Similarly, gulp.parallel with only one task as input should be same as the tast itself.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working.

```
gulp.task('do-nothing', function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        done()
    }, 3 * 1000)
})

gulp.task("default",

    gulp.parallel("do-nothing", function (done) {
      console.log(`\n\n\nWHY AM I NOT BEING RUN`)
      done()
    })

);
```